# How to write a go connection string for pgx.pool to a remote RDS?

Tags: go, pgx

I have no trouble connecting go `pgxpool` to a postgresql database in a docker container but can't figure out how to write a connection URL string for a linode postgresql RDS. Specifically, what is the first part of the URL "postgres://"? I can't find any example for a connection URL other than a local db and no code examples for a DSN connection.

Can somebody please help me out with either a connection URL or DSN for these details?

Here is my current connection string which returns "host is invalid". ssl_mode is also invalid.

```
config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig("user=linpostgres, password=secret, host=lin-9930-2356-pgsql-primary.servers.linodedb.net, port=5432 dbname=mydb, pool_max_conns=10")
```

This psq connect string times out: `psql --username=linpostgres --host=lin-9930-2356-pgsql-primary.servers.linodedb.net port=5432 --password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the code official GitHub repository code here: [link](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/d42b399be3ec4153ccd7e8b84ee50e60751a6936/pgxpool/pool.go#L305)

```
// See Config for definitions of these arguments.
//
//  # Example DSN 
//  user=jack password=secret host=pg.example.com port=5432 dbname=mydb sslmode=verify-ca pool_max_conns=10
//
//  # Example URL
//  postgres://jack:secret@pg.example.com:5432/mydb?sslmode=verify-ca&pool_max_conns=10
```

so your connection string should be

```
postgres://jack:secret@pg.example.com:5432/mydb?sslmode=verify-ca&pool_max_conns=10
```

hope this helps

Comment: I read the repository code but I still can't figure out the connection string or the DSN.

Comment: @markhorrocks it's normal connection string, you can just replace the jack with the with username, password and then port no / then db name? may I know where you are having trouble? Please post what your current connection string is.

Comment: I edited my question with the string.

Comment: @markhorrocks check if credentials are correct and please let me know the response with this one `config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig("user=linpostgres password=secret host=lin-9930-2356-pgsql-primary.servers.linodedb.net port=5432 dbname=mydb sslmode=require pool_max_conns=10")`

Comment: That timed out. There is a ca.crt to download from linode, should I add that to my docker container?

Comment: @markhorrocks try removing the sslmode=require?

Comment: That also timed out but psql is timing out as well. I added a string for psql to my question as well.

Comment: @markhorrocks ah, are you sure the port is open?

Comment: I had to open the port to 0.0.0.0/0 to test it but now I get no database exists for linpostgres. There is no console available apparently but that is a different question.